# Running ReadMe in Pythonnet

Tags: c#, python.net

Environment :

- Pythonnet version: 2.3.0, installed with pip in Amaconda3
- Python version: 3.6.6 using with Anaconda
- Visual Studio 2017 Community
- Operating System: Windows 7, 64 bit

I am running this example from Pythonnet wiki.

```
using (Py.GIL())
{
                dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
                Console.WriteLine(np.cos(np.pi * 2));

                dynamic sin = np.sin;
                Console.WriteLine(sin(5));

                double c = np.cos(5) + sin(5);
                Console.WriteLine(c);

                dynamic a = np.array(new List<float> { 1, 2, 3 });
                Console.WriteLine(a.dtype);

                dynamic b = np.array(new List<float> { 6, 5, 4 }, dtype: np.int32);
                Console.WriteLine(b.dtype);

                Console.WriteLine(a * b);
                Console.ReadKey();
}
```

result

```
1.0
-0.9589242746631385
-0.675262089199912
object
```

error occurs here :

```
dynamic b = np.array(new List { 6, 5, 4 }, dtype: np.int32);
```

error message :

```
Python.Runtime.PythonException: 'TypeError : int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]''
```

stack trace :

```
Python.Runtime.PythonException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=TypeError : int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
  Source=Python.Runtime
  StackTrace:
```

Tried Solution but no success :

1) https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/249

2) download zip file from master and run from Amaconda prompt

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel --xplat
pip install dist\pythonnet-2.4.0.dev0-cp36-cp36m-win64.whl
```

`python setup.py bdist_wheel` failed because need import error : mt.exe could not be found
I did not restart my pc while installing Visual Studio 2017 Community.
So, i think that Visual Studio 2017 Installer did not install mt.exe for me.
Restart PC is not an option for me.

===

Would Like to know is there any option to solve this issue, Thank You.

Comment: If you've solved your issue yourself, you should (and are encouraged to) post the solution and a brief explanation as an answer. You shouldn't include the solution as an edit to your question. Check out ["Can I answer my own question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in the [help].

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut noticed, thank for the remind.

Answer (score 1):

According to the developer of Pythonnet, i had tried to
install the master of pythonnet.

After the installation completed, i run ReadMe successfully.